# How do I use a pickerView and a UIbutton Object to go to different views based on what what item in the pickerView is selected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
@IBAction func EnterButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        switch(row)
        {
        case 0:
            let SecondViewController:secondViewController = secondViewController()
            self.presentViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        default:
            break

        }
    }
```

[image: This what I want to do]

Comment: The image link is below the question

Comment: Are you adding the buttons on the picker view??

Comment: I think you write all the description in the question title, coming to the answer, just get the index of the pickerview in Button Action with selectedRowInComponent method

Comment: would this be the way to select a different view controller?

Comment: let SecondViewController:secondViewController = secondViewController()
            self.presentViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: It just goes to a black screen when I run this method

Comment: @IBAction func EnterButton(sender: AnyObject){
            let selectedValue = regions[pickeroutlet.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
            let SecondViewController:secondViewController = secondViewController()
            if (selectedValue == "sardinia")
            {
                
                
                self.presentViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        
      
    }